# How to use one Nginx Cookie(route) in two upstreams with Nginx-sticky-module

Tags: nginx, load-balancing

I am using Nginx-sticky-module to add an upstream server persistance using cookies.But I have two upstreams like this:

```js
    upstream upstreamA{
        sticky;
        server server1:8080;
        server server2:8080;
    }
    upstream upstreamB{
        sticky;
        server server1:9080;
        server server2:9080;
    }

location /requestA {
    proxy_pass http://upstreamA;
}
location /requestB {
    proxy_pass http://upstreamB 
}
```

When user request nginx:port/requestA,Nginx can hold the request and distribute it to the same server.But if the user request nginx:port/requestB after requestA,Nginx will give it a new Set-Cookie value (route=xxx) by Nginx-sticky-module according upstreamB, can Nginx just use one Cookie in two upsteams?

Comment: I assume your upstream servers use some session cookie for user tracking already. You can reuse this cookie to calculate the hash. Lets suppose that your upstream is php server with standard session cookie name "PHPSESSID". then you can use ***hash '$cookie_PHPSESSID';*** in your upstream block definitions. There are a lot of "ifs" and "maybes" in this approach but my intuition tells me that chances are pretty good (if both lists have the same number of servers and sequence of servers are the same in both lists). If you find working solution please share it as an answer to your own question.